# Boostrap columns are not working properly with Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-ui

Please check the complete example below, Bootstrap is working perfectly fine outside Kendo-UI but the same html snippet inside the Kendo-UI is breaking Bootstrap Columns. I have added a working example below that shows just that in action. I don't understand what is casing this issue. Thanks in advance, appreciate your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: {
      open: {
        effects: "fadeIn"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Script -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap and Kendo UI Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery Library v3.3.1 -->

  <!-- Kendo v2016.1.226-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bg-primary">Column-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bg-danger">Column-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
      <div id="tabstrip">
        <ul>
          <li class="k-state-active">Paris</li>
          <li>New York</li>
          <li>London</li>
          <li>Moscow</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <!--***** Bootstrap in TAB-1 *****-->
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bg-primary">Column-1</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 bg-danger">Column-2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--***** END *****-->
          <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
          <div class="weather">
            <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
            <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="sunny">&nbsp;</span>
          <div class="weather">
            <h2>29<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
            <p>Sunny weather in New York.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="sunny">&nbsp;</span>
          <div class="weather">
            <h2>21<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
            <p>Sunny weather in London.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="cloudy">&nbsp;</span>
          <div class="weather">
            <h2>16<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
            <p>Cloudy weather in Moscow.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--**********END*********-->
    <style>
      .sunny,
      .cloudy,
      .rainy {
        display: block;
        margin: 30px auto 10px;
        width: 128px;
        height: 128px;
        background: url('../content/web/tabstrip/weather.png') transparent no-repeat 0 0;
      }
      
      .cloudy {
        background-position: -128px 0;
      }
      
      .rainy {
        background-position: -256px 0;
      }
      
      .weather {
        margin: 0 auto 30px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      #tabstrip h2 {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 5em;
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 0 0 0 30px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      #tabstrip h2 span {
        background: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
        font-size: .3em;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      
      #tabstrip p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used the demo from official webiste: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index AND used bootstrap template from www.w3schools.com

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nest-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout

Comment: ezanker: THANKS FOR YOUR SUPPORT!~

Answer (score 3):

*********** Official Doc by Telerik ***********
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nest-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout

Nest Widgets and Bootstrap Grid Layout

Kendo UI uses the default content-box box model (box-sizing CSS property), while Bootstrap uses the non-default border-box model and applies it to all elements on the page, including the ones that are unrelated to Bootstrap. This breaks the layout of the Kendo UI widgets, which are placed inside a Bootstrap grid layout, leading to the overriding of the Bootstrap CSS and reapplying the content-box box model to the widgets. As a result, a Bootstrap grid layout, placed inside a Kendo UI widget, is not going to work as expected. In general, the multiple-level nesting of the two products is bound to break the one that is on the inside, unless an additional CSS rule is used for each new level of nesting.

A possible easy workaround is to override the Bootstrap CSS, apply the content-box box model to all elements on the page and use a border-box box model only to the Bootstrap elements which need it. These are all .col-... classes, .row, .container, .container-fluid and form-control.

You can add the following CSS rules after the Bootstrap and Kendo UI stylesheets.

```
/* reset everything to the default box model */

*, :before, :after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/* set a border-box model only to elements that need it */

.form-control, /* if this class is applied to a Kendo UI widget, its layout may change */
.container,
.container-fluid,
.row,
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: However, I am not using this snippet of code and it seems to keep all my previews styles in good shape. I guess if you just started then keep using it all. In my case, I can't use it and if I do then I have to fix a lot of styles all over the site.

/* reset everything to the default box model */

*, :before, :after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}